# pyramid default page when deploying to production server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

I've managed to deploy to a production site, running on Apache + mod_wsgi, python3.3 + pyramid 1.4.
Right now, it's showing the pyramid default page.

I was messing around with the myapp folder, even when I removed `__init__.py`, restart apache, it is still showing the default pyramid page. Why is this so?

---

For some reason which I don't understand, when using install over develop, there's another
folder ( build ) being created, I've tried editing the template.pt file in build as well as
the one in the template folder, restart apache, it is still showing the default pyramid page that comes with when setting up a new project.

I don't know if this is the right way of doing it but it works for me. Instead of using install as detailed in http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html, step 6:

```
    $ ../bin/python setup.py install
```

I used develop, edited the template.pt in the template folder, restart apache, and the site is
reflecting the changes.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean "pyramid default page"? There isn't nearly enough info about your app in here to have any clue what removing one file would do.

Comment: edited, hope it clears things up

Comment: Are you using `virtualenv`?

Comment: yes, i'm just following the modwsgi deployment instructions

Comment: @Gino I think you are slightly mistaken. Once you do `python setup.py install`, the view and template folders are installed in your virtualenv Look in `/path/to/your//env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/your_project`. Editing anything _there_ and restarting APache will reflect those changes. `develop` is just a fancy way of saying - I am installing the package in my current directory

Answer (score 1):

`install` bundles your app, and will not include static files unless you have a proper MANIFEST. `develop` is usually a better way to deploy unless you're trying to make your app redistributable as an open project.

Comment: aye, after hours of fiddling, I have to agree with you on that. =D. Thanks